# Python post to a single discord channel in 1 line

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a single line I can use to post to a discord channel?
that is, if I define the channel etc first.

UPDATE:

```
import json
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper
from configparser import RawConfigParser
from datetime import datetime


def log(text):
    print('[%s] %s' % (datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S'), text))

def load_configini():
    config = RawConfigParser()
    with open('scumlogs.ini', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        config.read_file(f)
    global configini
    configini = dict(config['GPORTAL'])

def save_configini():
    parser = RawConfigParser()
    parser.add_section('GPORTAL')
    for key in configini.keys():
        parser.set('GPORTAL', key, configini[key])
    with open('scumlogs.ini', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        parser.write(f)


async def read_logs():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'

    }
    values = ('user','password','serverid','loc','folder','admin_file','admin_line','chat_file','chat_line','kill_file','kill_line','login_file','login_line','violations_file','violations_line')
    print('scumlogs v1.0, scum server logs downloader from gportal\nby htttps://GAMEBotLand.com')
    try:
        load_configini()
    except:
        global configini
        configini = {}
    for value in values:
        if value not in configini:
            configini[value] = ''
    if configini['folder'] != '':
        if configini['folder'][-1:] != '/' and configini['folder'][-1:] != '\\':
            configini['folder'] = configini['folder'] + '/'
    save_configini()

    if configini['loc'] == 'com':
        loc = 'com'
    else:
        loc = 'us'
    URL_LOGIN = 'https://id2.g-portal.com/login?redirect=https://www.g-portal.{}/en/gportalid/login?'.format(configini['loc'])
    URL_LOGS = 'https://www.g-portal.{}/en/scum/logs/{}'.format(configini['loc'], configini['serverid'])

    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        try:
            log('connecting g-portal...')
            payload = {'_method': 'POST', 'login': configini['user'], 'password': configini['password'],
                       'rememberme': '1'}
            async with session.post(URL_LOGIN, data=payload, headers=headers) as raw_response:
                response = await raw_response.text()
            async with session.get(URL_LOGS) as raw_response:
                response = await raw_response.text()
            html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
            select = html.find('div', {'class': 'wrapper logs'})
            loglist = select['data-logs']
            logs = json.loads(loglist)

            for i in range(len(logs)):
                getid = logs["file_" + str(i + 1)]
                id = (getid[int(getid.find('Logs')) + 5:])
                type = id.split('_')[0]

                if configini[type + '_file'] != '':
                    if id < configini[type + '_file']:
                        continue
                payload = {'_method': 'POST', 'load': 'true', 'ExtConfig[config]': getid}
                async with session.post(URL_LOGS, data=payload, headers=headers) as raw_response:
                    response = await raw_response.text()
                content = json.loads(response)
                lines = content["ExtConfig"]["content"].splitlines()
                filename = configini['folder'] + id
                file = open(filename, "a+", encoding='utf-8')
                found = False
                writing = False
                for line in lines:
                    if id == configini[type + '_file'] and not found:
                        if line == configini[type + '_line']:
                            found = True
                            continue
                    else:                    
                        file.write(line + '\n')                       
                        writing = True
                if writing:
                    if found:
                        log('updating {}'.format(id))
                    else:
                        log('creating {}'.format(id))
                file.close()
                configini[type + '_file'] = id
                configini[type + '_line'] = lines[-1]

            save_configini()
        except:
            log('error connecting, check connectivity and scumlogs.ini')
        await session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(read_logs())
    loop.close()
```

The part 2/3 down that is marked as "Doesnt work" is why I was asking the question.
I do not know python well enough to know why the bot is not posting to the channel.
I htought a 1 line with all the client.send(token) stuff in it might be the answer.
Thanks.

Original log extract code:

```
import json
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper
from configparser import ConfigParser
from datetime import datetime

def log(text):
    print('[%s] %s' % (datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S'), text))


def load_configini():
    config = ConfigParser()
    with open('scumlogs.ini', 'r') as f:
        config.read_file(f)
    global configini
    configini = dict(config['GPORTAL'])

def save_configini():
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.add_section('GPORTAL')
    for key in configini.keys():
        parser.set('GPORTAL', key, configini[key])
    with open('scumlogs.ini', 'w') as f:
        parser.write(f)


async def read_logs():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'

    }
    values = ('user','password','serverid','loc','folder','admin_file','admin_line','chat_file','chat_line','kill_file','kill_line','login_file','login_line','violations_file','violations_line')
    print('scumlogs v1.0, scum server logs downloader from gportal\nby https://GAMEBotLand.com')
    try:
        load_configini()
    except:
        global configini
        configini = {}
    for value in values:
        if value not in configini:
            configini[value] = ''
    save_configini()

    if configini['loc'] == 'com':
        loc = 'com'
    else:
        loc = 'us'
    URL_LOGIN = 'https://id2.g-portal.com/login?redirect=https://www.g-portal.{}/en/gportalid/login?'.format(configini['loc'])
    URL_LOGS = 'https://www.g-portal.{}/en/scum/logs/{}'.format(configini['loc'], configini['serverid'])

    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        try:
            log('connecting g-portal...')
            payload = {'_method': 'POST', 'login': configini['user'], 'password': configini['password'],
                       'rememberme': '1'}
            async with session.post(URL_LOGIN, data=payload, headers=headers) as raw_response:
                response = await raw_response.text()
            async with session.get(URL_LOGS, headers=headers) as raw_response:
                response = await raw_response.text()
            html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
            select = html.find('div', {'class': 'wrapper logs'})
            loglist = select['data-logs']
            logs = json.loads(loglist)

            if configini['folder'] != '':
                if configini['folder'][-1:] != '/' and configini['folder'][-1:] != '\\':
                    configini['folder'] = configini['folder'] + '/'

            for i in range(len(logs)):
                getid = logs["file_" + str(i + 1)]
                id = (getid[int(getid.find('Logs')) + 5:])
                type = id.split('_')[0]

                if configini[type + '_file'] != '':
                    if id < configini[type + '_file']:
                        continue
                payload = {'_method': 'POST', 'load': 'true', 'ExtConfig[config]': getid}
                async with session.post(URL_LOGS, data=payload, headers=headers) as raw_response:
                    response = await raw_response.text()
                content = json.loads(response)
                lines = content["ExtConfig"]["content"].splitlines()
                filename = configini['folder'] + type
                file = open(filename, "a+", encoding='utf-8')
                found = False
                writing = False
                for line in lines:
                    if id == configini[type + '_file'] and not found:
                        if line == configini[type + '_line']:
                            found = True
                            continue
                    else:
                        file.write(line + '\n')
                        writing = True
                if writing:
                    if found:
                        log('updating {}'.format(id))
                    else:
                        log('creating {}'.format(id))
                file.close()
                configini[type + '_file'] = id
                configini[type + '_line'] = lines[-1]

            save_configini()
        except:
            log('error connecting, check connectivity and scumlogs.ini')
        await session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(read_logs())
    loop.close()
```

And this is the "post to discord bot" code that works.

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

TOKEN = '0000000000000000.XkEdpg.Iu9OsHVck-qrANPXop39ZMm78f4'
global client
client = discord.Client()
global channel
channel = '0000000000000000000000'




@client.event
async def on_ready():
    msg = 'Test Bot ready to post logs'
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.name == 'server-logs':
                await client.send_message(channel, msg)
                print(channel)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

What I am trying to do is get the lines from the first code, that get put into a file, out put to the discord bot

Comment: Ok. I have edited original question to show what I have but cannot work out.

Comment: 1 part extracts logs from a website. The bot part is supposed to interate each line of the logs to the bot. I can make a bot post to s a channel and I can get the logs to  download, but I cannot get a script to 'do both'

Comment: @cricket_007 There is some code. Are you able to help?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would like to point out before giving your answer.
To begin with, you do not need to global your variables outside of a function, as them being outside of the function makes them global anyway.

Secondly, you must understand how discord.py actually works in order to do this, and the method you are using to do this simply won't work.

What you really should be doing is having these functions separate to the functions used for the discord.py functions, then having a command or event inside of the discord.py functions that call into the functions you made earlier on.

May i suggest you read up on PEP8 as well as take what I said into consideration; then rewrite your code as this won't work and from what I can see; is inefficient and poorly written (in the nicest possible way).

Keep on learning!

Comment: Thanks Tylerr. You gave me something to look for with the PEP8 guidance. I'm not a coder, btw. I cut and pasted various things together and I dont really get how functions etc work so I truly have no idea...  is why it s poorly written code. May I post the 2 pieces of code I am trying to amalgimate and you give me some guidance? Above is my attempt at putting them together. The 2 originals might show more fo what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Tylerr. I have added to the orig post with orig code I used. Thank you.